# Is it possible for a Kafka stream to write output to two different topics?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I need a stream to group values from topic A, send the grouped values to topic B, and send the sum of those grouped values over a tumbling time window to topic C.
Is it possible to do that in Kafka? Or can a stream both read and write from one topic only?

Comment: Have you tried using the `to` method more than once? What happened?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. For example you can split a input stream and write to different topics:

```java
KStream stream = ...
KStream[] splitStream = stream.branch(...);

splitStream[0].to("topic-1");
splitStream[1].to("topic-2");
```

You can also use a more dynamic approach via `to(TopicNameExtractor)`.

You can also "broadcast" a stream to apply different logic. Reusing the same `KStream` variable ensures that each record is logically duplicated and processed through multiple parallel downstream operations:

```java
KStream stream = ...

KStream filterdStream = stream.filter();
KTable count = stream.groupBy().count();
```

Comment: Hello, do you have some example of using to(TopicNameExtractor)?

Comment: This blog post might help: https://www.confluent.io/blog/putting-events-in-their-place-with-dynamic-routing/

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax I still don't see how to broadcast to multiple topics. One I use the to() method; the stream ends.

Comment: This should help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74905757/one-kstream-to-multiple-topics-using-duplicate-messages-broadcast