# One KStream to multiple topics using duplicate messages; broadcast

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

In a Kafka streaming topology, I would like to route a stream from an incoming topic using a KStream, enhance the message, and output to a destination topic. In the middle of the stream however, I'd also like to send all the messages to another topic.

```
KStream<Integer, GenericRecord> ksDevice = builder.stream("source_topic", Consumed.with(Serdes.Integer(), genericRecordSerde));

KStream<Integer, GenericRecord> ksEnhance = builder.stream("enhance_topic", Consumed.with(Serdes.Integer(), genericRecordSerde));

ksDevice.join(ksEnhance, (k, v) -> /* enhance message */))
.to("orthogonal_topic")
.to("destination_topic")
```

This obviously isn't possible because .to() terminates the stream.
I also can't use kstream.branch() because this will send the message to either one topic or the other; I need to send all messages to both topics.

I saw a post where the author suggested that you can do this by using kstream.filter().to("topic")
kstream.filter().to("topic")
[Streaming messages to multiple topics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42388525/streaming-messages-to-multiple-topics)
But I can't see how this is done without terminating the stream.

Comment: if your design is not much restrictive, than i would suggest you to send it to one topic only, but create two consumers with different consumer group name so it will be consumed duplicate in two different consumer. as i would not suggest to duplicate data/stream on kafka until its really un-avoidable.

Comment: @NiravChhatrola Thanks for the feedback. That was my optional solution but I preferred not to create a new topology just to populate a sink status update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The linked post is correct. In your case, you don't need a filter. Create an intermediate variable

```
KStream k = ksDevice.join(...)
k.to()
k.to()
```

Alternatively, use `.through().to()`.

But as commented, you're needlessly duplicating the exact same data on the broker. Two distinct consumer groups can be used instead to read from one topic.